# how to query sqlite when there are more than one condition that needs to be met

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I am using a content provider and need to query a table where one column of the row = thing1 and another column of that same row = thing2.
i know you can query a table for just one condition like:

```
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(content_uri, projection, variable + "='" + thing1 + "'", null, null);
```

now how can i query for two conditions? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(content_uri, projection, "col1=? AND col2=?", args, null);
```

where `args` is a `String[]` of values to substitute in for the `?` in the query.

Comment: ok thanks and to clarify, col1's ? will go to the first string in the array and col2's ? will go to the second string in the array? also i need both conditions to be met, so i can use AND instead of OR right?

Comment: @What2107: Yes, sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I have adjusted my suggested source. "col1's ? will go to the first string in the array and col2's ? will go to the second string in the array?" -- yes. "also i need both conditions to be met, so i can use AND instead of OR right?" -- yes (see adjusted source).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(content_uri, projection, variable + "='" + thing1 + "' AND "+variable2 + "='"+thing2+"'"  ,  null, null);
```